# PHP arithmetic operation outputs strange result (array-related)

Tags: php

I have two variables which is as follows:

```
$ccharge = ($user_info[0]['charge']) - ($get_exam[0]['price']);
```

But it results -150000.

Both numbers are 150000 which should result 0, but it doesn't. Is this a familiar issue?

**I have found the issue** which is related to arrays. I have assigned them to simple variables and it has worked. But I want to know for my future projects.

why such formula causes problems?

Comment: Are the values stored as strings?

Comment: Use var_dump on each value and it should be clear as to what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $ccharge = ((float)$user_info[0]['charge']) - ((float)$get_exam[0]['price']);
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the unexpected result occurs.

Comment: this will cast it to float no matter string or int.

Comment: Why would you want it casted to float?